# Using $slice with $map on $lookup in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

-
Hi , i have an aggregation query with lookup, i need to project specific fields from this lookup and slice them. This is what I've done so far.

```
{
$lookup: {
  from: 'users',
  localField: 'users',
  foreignField: '_id',
  as: 'users',
}},
```

I've added the unwind statement

```
{
$unwind: {
  path: '$users',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}},
```

I've added the group statement

`{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: '$_id',
        createdAt: '$createdAt',
        updatedAt: '$updatedAt'
      },
      users: {
        $addToSet: '$users',
      }
    }
  },`

And to project specific fields in array of users i did:

```
{
$project: {
  _id: '$_id._id',
  createdAt: '$_id.createdAt',
  updatedAt: '$_id.updatedAt',
  // users: {
  //   $slice: [
  //     "$users",
  //     skip,
  //     limit
  //   ]
  // },
  users: {
    $map: {
        input: '$users',
        as: 'user',
        in: {
          email: '$$user.email',
          name: '$$user.name',
          username: '$$user.username',
          updatedAt: '$$user.updatedAt'
        }
     }
  }
}},
```

My question is , How can i use $slice in this scope ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how **'legit'** is this but , I've added fields to **$addToSet** statement in **$group** , so now i can use **$slice** with **mapped fields**.

```
{
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: '$_id',
        createdAt: '$createdAt',
        updatedAt: '$updatedAt',
      },
      users: {
        $addToSet: {
          _id: '$users._id',
          email: '$users.email',
          name: '$users.name',
          username: '$users.username',
          updatedAt: '$users.updatedAt'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Now i can easily do **$slice** in **$project** statement.

```
{
    $project: {
      _id: '$_id._id',
      users: {
        $slice: [
          "$users",
          skip,
          limit
        ]
      }
    },
  }
```

If someone has a better solution , i would like to know.